# Unable to generate signed APK in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, build, apk

I'm using Masayukisuda GPU Video Library , and my app is working great in debug Apk but when trying to build the release APK then getting the below error message.

Type com.daasuu.gpuv.camerarecorder.CameraHandler is defined multiple times: E:\MOJ VIDEOS\My APP\app\build\intermediates\project_dex_archive\release\out\com\daasuu\gpuv\camerarecorder\CameraHandler.dex, E:\MOJ VIDEOS\My APP\app\build\intermediates\external_libs_dex\release\mergeExtDexRelease\classes.dex

Comment: were u able to fix this?